# A SQL query optimzation issue with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, order-by, tuning

An SQL query optimzation issue with ORDER BY

Current status
I have a database of Chess games and their corresponding moves (stored as strings called fens). I have two main tables 'Game' and 'GamePosition'. GamePosition has an index on the fen column and Game has an index on white_elo. I currently have 170471 games and 14813401 positions. I'm running mysql 5.7.28.

Object
I'm trying to fetch top rated games based on elo rating of the players. I've simplified my query a bit here, but the point and performance problem is the same.

```
SELECT Game.id
FROM Game
JOIN GamePosition ON Game.id = game_id
WHERE fen = 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR'
ORDER BY white_elo DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query tends to be a bit slow (1.2 s) if I get a lot of results (typically the first move gives 67k+ results). Since I plan to exand the database 10x at least, I want to optimize my query. I've run a EXPLAIN which shows that it needs to do a filesort before finding the top rated games on all the results. This seems to be the issue. Removing the ORDER BY from the query makes it superfast (0.0008 s). 
[image]

Any ideas if it's possible to optimize the query, or if I could store the data differently?

UPDATE:

```
       Table: GamePosition
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `GamePosition` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fen` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `move_color` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `castling_rights` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `en_passant_square` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `half_move` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `full_move` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` time DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'time in video',
  `move` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_square` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_square` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `position_ibfk_1` (`game_id`),
  KEY `fen` (`fen`),
  KEY `parent_position` (`parent_position`),
  CONSTRAINT `game_key` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `Game` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

       Table: Game
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pgn` text NOT NULL,
  `white_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `black_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `white_elo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `black_elo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0=white, 1=draw 2=black',
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eco` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event_key` (`event_id`),
  KEY `black_key` (`black_id`),
  KEY `white_key` (`white_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `black_key` FOREIGN KEY (`black_id`) REFERENCES `Player` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_key` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `Event` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `white_key` FOREIGN KEY (`white_id`) REFERENCES `Player` (`id`)
)

       Table: Player
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Player` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_unique` (`id`)
)
```

Actual Query

```
SELECT GamePosition.id AS position_id, Game.id AS id,
       white.name AS white, black.name AS black, Game.id,
       white_elo, black_elo, result, date
    FROM Game
    JOIN GamePosition ON Game.id = game_id
    JOIN Player white ON white.id = white_id
    JOIN Player black ON black.id = black_id
    WHERE fen = '$fen'
    ORDER BY white_elo+black_elo DESC
    LIMIT $limit
    OFFSET $offset";
```

Kind Regards,
Bjorn

Comment: Can't give optimization advice without knowing which table each column is in.  Please qualify the rest of the columns and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I've updated with the info you asked for

Comment: Can't the same "position" occur in a game more than once?  (Granted, I think it is very rare.)  Does `fen` uniquely identify where all the pieces are?

Comment: @RickJames: Yes, the same position can occur more than once, but it's a very small problem, in my case I want to retrieve both positions. 

FEN uniquely identifies the pieces:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth–Edwards_Notation

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to avoid a filesort on this one is if you maintain a materialized view of a JOIN between Game and GamePosition, so that you can create an index across (fen, white_elo).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a different strategy for the first move.  After that, you schema and query may work well.

Guessing at which columns are in which tables, I think you need

```
INDEX(fen, game_id)
```

"I've simplified my query a bit here" -- Caveat:  any advice given for the 'simplified' query *may or may not* still apply to the real query.

This *might* work for the first move:

```
SELECT 
    FROM Game AS g
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM GamePosition
               WHERE game_id = g.id
                 AND fen = 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR' )
    ORDER BY white_elo DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

The risk is that for some odd first move, it will need to scan through a million rows to find 10.  A workaround for that is to fetch the top-10 nightly and save them.  That effectively gives you a list of 10 games that is constant "enough" for what you are doing.

**More**

After the first move, turning the query inside-out may help.  The principle is to get through with the `LIMIT` asap.

(I am assuming `result` is in `Game`???  Please qualify all columns when joining; it makes it easier to read.)
(Game.id seems to be fetched twice?)

```
SELECT x.position_id,
       x.game_id,
       w.name AS white, b.name AS black,
       g.white_elo, g.black_elo, g.result, g.date
    FROM ( SELECT gp.id AS position_id,
                  g1.id AS game_id
              FROM GamePosition AS gp
              JOIN Game AS g1  ON g1.id = gp.game_id'
              WHERE gp.fen = '$fen'
              ORDER BY g1.white_elo + g1.black_elo DESC
              LIMIT $limit
              OFFSET $offset
         ) AS x
    JOIN Game AS g2 ON x.game_id = g2.id
    JOIN Player white ON white.id = g2.white_id
    JOIN Player black ON black.id = g2.black_id
```

Index:

```
GamePosition:  INDEX(fen, game_id, id)
```